# Generate html from "{Input:{'A':'System.Int32','B':'System.Int32'}, Output:System.Int32}"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, metadata

I get metadata as string like "{Input:{'A':'System.Int32','B':'System.Int32'}, Output:System.Int32}"

I am using knockout.js and could use json.parse also. But are there any easy way to generate a inputform that let the user submit data for properties of input. (would it be better to change the metadata to be a list of properties?

Comment: If you use knockout it should be possible to create input that will fit that framework - but a for-in plus a for-in should handle the above

Comment: Do you mean i should change the metadata generator ?

Comment: You can, but you can also change it in the page to conform to the framework. Sounds safer to me. Your data looks like valid JSON

Comment: How is that metadata supposed to relate to the HTML you want to generate? I suppose the inputs should be input elements with the names `A` and `B` meant for numbers... but what is output supposed to represent? You need to _clearly_ define what you're doing. Sure knockout can generate stuff for you but you're not giving us much to work with.

Comment: I just found out that JSON.parse dont handle ' ? but have to use "

Comment: And ye, the output should just be omitted, sorry.

Comment: But i think i solved it yes, i am creating a template that uses foreach on the properties and it generate input fields. Need to figure out if i can convert the types to some kind of validation scheme

Comment: Thanks for helping out, i attached my answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to generate the array of properties.

```
self.input = ko.observableArray([]);
if (data.MetaData) {
  //  alert(data.MetaData);
    var d = JSON.parse(data.MetaData).Input;
    for (var prop in d) {
        self.input.push({name:ko.observable(prop),type:d[prop],value:ko.observable('')});
    }
}
```

and View:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach:test().input">
        <li >
            <label data-bind="text:name, uniqueFor: name"></label>
            <input placeholder="value" data-bind="value:value, uniqueId: name"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and bindings:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value.id = value.id || ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.prefix + (++ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.counter);

        element.id = value.id;
    },
    counter: 0,
    prefix: "unique"
};

ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueFor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value.id = value.id || ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.prefix + (++ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.counter);

        element.setAttribute("for", value.id);
    }
};
```